# Programatically deactivating a feature in Internet Explorer

Tags: c#, .net, html, internet-explorer, coding-style

I'm currently developing a plug in for Internet Explorer, and there's a certain feature in Internet Explorer that's bothering me.

There's this feature in IE that's been appearing at least since IE7 (I couldn't check earlier versions), that lets the user modify the sizing of HTML elements in editable windows (such as a rich text mail in GMail), just by clicking on the element and dragging the sizing box. This modifies the style of the HTML element (such as a `<img>` or a `<div>`).

My first problem is that I don't know the name of that feature. I've searched and searched, but I haven't been able to find a thing.

My second problem is that I need a way to either turn it off, or at least to work with it, programatically. In my plug in, I need to modify the DOM in webmail clients to modify certain things that the user types. The problem is that for some reason, the behaviour of my plugin varies if an HTML element is selected using this feature in the edit window of the webmail. I need to, at the very least, be able to detect if anything is selected this way.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This may not be what you want to hear, but my eyesight requires me to make changes like this so I would be bummed if your plug-in did this to me.

Comment: I'm more interested in unselecting anything selected than turn off the whole thing. It's only having a selected element what's getting in the way.

Answer (score 3):

You're probably talking about [Internet Explorer's Accessibility Features](http://www.microsoft.com/enable/products/ie7/default.aspx), which are designed to assist the visually impaired to use websites. Visual impairement can take many forms, and it's generally considered *very bad form* to take away any tools designed to assist users in their efforts to effectively use the Internet.

Don't make your users work harder to use your site. You get paid to write software that's easy to use and makes life simpler. If your site doesn't do that, your users will find one that does.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't think it's any accesibility feature though. The one I'm referring to is only visible when editing a rich text surface, such as a webmail. I think it's more related to editting the style in the mail, to change sizes of different element. From what I've seen, these size changes modify the CSS styling of the HTML element, so it's more than just changing sizes for visibility; whatever size you're changing is sent along with the mail, and is there for everyone to see, wherever they are.